# Python string index out of bounds

Tags: python

I want to reverse a string like so:

```
def reverse(s):
    for i in range(len(s),0,-1):
        var = s[i] # getting an out of range error?
        ...
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: len(s) == N, s[N] is out of bounds, the last valid index is N-1

Comment: do `for i in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1)` instead

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses! I understand now :)

Comment: I find `reversed(range(len(s)))` more readable than `range(len(s)-1,-1,-1)`

Comment: FYI there is a easier way `s[::-1]` would also reverse the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a string length is `n`, the valid indexes are from `0` to `n-1` (the elements are counted from 0 not from 1).

In your code the `for` loop condition `len(s)` should be changed into `len(s) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and simple answer! Will accept the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

simplicis's answer is so good, but here is an easy way to reverse a string like this:

```
print('Hello'[::-1])
```

Output:

```
olleH
```

Comment: Thanks for the response as well! I'm doing a Codecademy tutorial, and they specifically instructed not to use it that way ;) but I appreciate it!

Comment: Okay, just a tip. If you want to reverse a string, this is the best way :P